# Why is my footer not staying centered?

Tags: html, css, styling

Can someone tell me why my footer is not staying in the middle when you make the browser window smaller?

```
[removed]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give `min-width:1093px` to the `body` element

Answer (score 1):

Because the images are too wide. You should turn the red bars into a background image.

Answer (score 0):

It is staying in the middle. Of the body, which is it's parent. When the window resizes, body resizes. You need a wrapper that has a fixed width to contain all your centralized content.

Answer (score 0):

Put it inside your "fauxcolumns" wrapper, absolutely-positioned to the bottom and add enough padding at the bottom of "fauxcolumns" to make sure it doesn't collide with your content.

Answer (score 0):

Your images in the footer have their own width.   It stays centered for me if I remove the images and put

```
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right:auto;
```

on the div id="legal"